# Laravel No messages error while redirecting

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting NoMessages error while redirecting to a page.

```
add.blade.php
```

```html
@extends('layout.app')
@section('content')
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'AddluggageController@addconfirm','method'=>'POST']) !!}
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <h5 class="col-12"><b> Passenger Info</b> </h5> 
        <div class="col-12">
            {{form::label('name'), 'Name'}} 
            {{form::text('name','',['class'=>'form-control '])}} <br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            {{form::label('phone'), 'Phone'}} 
            {{form::text('phone','',['class'=>'form-control '])}}
        </div>
    </div>
sni</div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

AddluggageController.php

```
    public function addconfirm(){
     return redirect('/addsuccess')->with('success', 'Saved Successfully');
    }
```

web.php

Route::post('/addconfirm', 'AddluggageController@addconfirm');

when I redirect it gives me

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

No message

Comment: How you open this `add.blade.php` file ? in controller method ?

Comment: no this is `post` type `Route::post('/addconfirm'` I am saying about `get` as I did in answer check my answer

Comment: no. I opened from nave bar using the route

Comment: Route::get('/add', 'AddluggageController@add')->middleware('auth');

Comment: then change inside controller as `return redirect('/addluggage')->with('success', 'Saved Successfully');` not to `addsuccess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your comment you need to change route name to `addluggage` from `addsuccess`

```
 return redirect('/addluggage')->with('success', 'Saved Successfully');
```

Whenever you redirect it have `get` not `post` so change in controller where you redirect

```
public function addconfirm(){
   return view('addconfirm')->with('success', 'Saved Successfully');
   // here "addconfirm" is blade name as "addconfirm.blade.php" inside "resoruces/views" folder
}
```

You can also change from `action` to `url`

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/addconfirm','method'=>'POST']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your route method to `GET`:
`Route::get('/addconfirm', 'AddluggageController@addconfirm');`

then add following to your blade:

`@if (\Session::has('success'))`
          `{!! \Session::get('success') !!}`
        
`@endif`